# why does my connect fail?

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming

I am trying to do basic socket calls, and trying to connect to google.com but the connect call always fails and returns -1. Any reason why it must be failing

```
int main()
{
    int sockfd;
    struct addrinfo *ai;
    char port[4];
    if(sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) < 0) {
        printf("socket return -1");
    }
    sprintf(port, "%d", 80);
    if(getaddrinfo("www.google.com", port, NULL, &ai) < 0)
        printf("-2\n");

    if(connect(sockfd, ai->ai_addr, sizeof(*ai->ai_addr)) < 0)
        printf("connect failed -1");
}
```

Comment: Try `sizeof(ai->ai_addr)`. Also print out what's in `ai` after `getaddrinfo()` to make sure it's sensible.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with the parameter `sizeof(*ai->ai_addr)`. ai->ai_addr returns a pointer to a sockaddr struct, and dereferencing brings you to the struct itself.

```
struct sockaddr {
   unsigned short sa_family;   // address family, AF_xxx
   char           sa_data[14]; // 14 bytes of protocol address
};
```

sizeof is returning the size of the entire struct, not the length of the address.

Try making the argument `ai->ai_addrlen` instead.

Comment: Hmm, well connect() will set errno when it fails. How about using perror() and posting the result?